# If list contains string print all the indexes / elements in the list that contain it

Tags: python, string, list, loops, search

I am able to detect matches but unable to locate where are they.

Given the following list:

```
['A second goldfish is nice and all', 3456, 'test nice']
```

I need to search for match (i.e. "nice") and print all the list elements that contain it. Ideally if the keyword to search were "nice" the results should be:

```
'A second goldfish is nice and all'
'test nice'
```

I have:

```
list = data_array
string = str(raw_input("Search keyword: "))
print string
if any(string in s for s in list):
    print "Yes"
```

So it finds the match and prints both, the keyword and "Yes" but it doesn't tell me where it is.

Should I iterate through every index in list and for each iteration search "string in s" or there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
list = data_array
string = str(raw_input("Search keyword: "))
print string
for s in list:
    if string in str(s):
        print 'Yes'
        print list.index(s)
```

Editted to working example. If you only want the first matching index you can also break after the if statement evaluates true

Comment: I did, it told me that the list did not contain such index. I think I am just getting it by looping through each records and searching every time. Is just a slow method.

Comment: This won't work, because `string in s` returns True if `string` is a substring of `s`, but `list.index(string)` will only find where it is is string is an `element` in `list`.

Comment: I've edited to fix this DSM. Is there an advantage to using list comprehensions like posted by Dan and bainikolaus? I find my version much more readable

Answer (score 3):

```
matches = [s for s in my_list if my_string in str(s)]
```

or

```
matches = filter(lambda s: my_string in str(s), my_list)
```

Note that `'nice' in 3456` will raise a `TypeError`, which is why I used `str()` on the list elements. Whether that's appropriate depends on if you want to consider `'45'` to be in `3456` or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
print filter(lambda s: k in str(s), l)
```

Answer (score 1):

To print all the elements that contains nice

```
mylist = ['nice1', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'nice2', 'nice3']
sub = 'nice'
print("\n".join([e for e in mylist if sub in e]))
>>> nice1
    nice2
    nice3
```

To get the index of elements that contain nice (irrespective of the letter case)

```
mylist = ['nice1', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'Nice2', 'NicE3']
sub = 'nice'
index_list = []
i = 0
for e in mylist:
    if sub in e.lower():
        index_list.append(i)
    i +=1
print(index_list)
>>> [0, 3, 4]
```